# Selecting a directory like counsel-find-file

Tags: ivy, directories, counsel, completing-read

I would like to write a function that would prompt the user to select a directory, using an UI like that presented by `counsel-find-file`.

The starting directory should be an arbitrary directory passed to this function as an argument.

This function should only show the user directories, not files, and the user should be able to navigate up and down the filesystem just as in `counsel-find-file`.

When the user makes their selection by hitting the `RETURN` key, the path to the selected directory should be returned to the calling function.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 3):

I just figured this out myself (using `counsel-dired` as a model):

```cl
(defun my-counsel-find-directory (&optional start-dir)
  "Return a directory chosen by the user.
The user is prompted to choose a directory starting with START-DIR."
  (let ((ivy-read-prompt "Choose directory: ")
        (counsel--find-file-predicate #'file-directory-p)
        (default-directory (or start-dir default-directory)))
    (ivy-read
     ivy-read-prompt
     #'read-file-name-internal
     :matcher #'counsel--find-file-matcher)))
```

Comment: How do I get this source code to be highlighted as elisp?

Comment: StackExchange/Overflow [switched](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983/goodbye-prettify-hello-highlight-js-swapping-out-our-syntax-highlighter) from Prettify to highlight.js recently, and Prettify supports elisp, but highlight.js does not, you can use clojure/common-lisp/scheme/etc instead if you want, see https://emacs.stackexchange.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting